# converting array of bytes to UTF-8 unicode

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode, utf-8

I have a file saved as UTF-8, and i'm reading it like this:

```
ReadFile(hFile, pContents, pFile->nFileSize, &dwRead, NULL);
```

(pContents is a BYTE* of size nFileSize)

its just a small file with 100 bytes or so, contains text which i want to read into memory in wchar_t* format, so i can set the text of edit and static controls with the unicode text.

How can i convert the bytes to UTF-8?

edit (i don't want to use fstream or wfstream)

Comment: The bytes *are* already UTF-8, if you are reading UTF-8 encoded text. Neither C++ nor C care about the encoding, they just see an array of bytes. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i thought utf-8 was multibyte, like it needed sometimes 2 bytes to finish a character, mines just reading it into a byte array

Comment: UTF-8 uses between 1 and 4 bytes per character.  But that is irrelevant if you are just treating it as a byte array.

Comment: Right. So 2, 3, or 4 bytes from the array may together determine a character. This is UTF-8. You can't "convert" that into UTF-8 because it's already UTF-8. You *could* convert it to UTF-32 for processing characters, but this is rarely useful in practice unless you're doing high-level text processing. Just leave it as UTF-8 unless you know a reason that won't work.

Comment: if you wanted to know what i was doing, i have my own function which reads the file, and accesses the array e.g. pBuffer[10], if it was multibyte then i could get unfinished data, so i needed to convert it to unicode (2bytes per characeter) and access it 2 bytes at a time

Comment: Unicode is not 2 bytes per character. Unicode is 21 bits (which normally requires 32 bits of storage unless you can pack it) per character.

Comment: There are multiple Unicode encodings. UTF-8 uses anything from 8 bits to 32 bits per codepoint, UTF-16 uses one or two 16 bits "code units" per codepoint, and UTF-32 uses 32 bits for every codepoint. The only way you could be certain that you will not run into "unfinished" characters would be to convert your data to UTF-32 and store each character using 4 bytes.

Comment: You only *need* the Unicode code points to look up character properties like casing.  If you have a program that takes action on ASCII characters while passing non-ASCII bytes around as-is (e.g., writing a CSV parser where only `,`, `"`, and `\n` have syntactic significance), then you can just leave your strings as UTF-8.  That ASCII-compatibility was why UTF-8 was invented in the first place.

Comment: Dan brings up a good point here. You may not need to worry about the encoding at all, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 (wchar_t).
- [`WideCharToMuliByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is in UTF-8 and you read it into an array.
Then it is still in UTF-8 format and you don;t need to do anything.

Comment: While this is correct in the technical sense of the word and doesn't deserve the downvote, it is non-the-less a tongue in cheek answer. Yes those bytes still represent a UTF-8 string, but they cannot be manipulated as such. You cannot even ask the question "How many characters do i have?" much less ask it to "Remove the last character".

Comment: @Volodya: Its not meant as tongue in cheek and the only correct answer provided. The other two answers are incorrect. As they convert a UTF-8 array into UTF-16 array (The OP specifically requested a UTF-8 array (see question)).

Comment: You point out a characteristic weakness in your comment about variable width character formats that has nothing to do with this question. Just like the above conversion functions there are equivalent functions to find the string length of a MBC string. You will also note that you can not find the string length directly for UTF-16 (as it is also a multi byte character format (you need to know where the [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) are and count them differently)).

Answer (score 1):

```
int res2 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, tempBuf.c_str(), -1, 
                               multiByteBuf, lengthOfInputString, NULL, NULL);
int res = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, wcharBuf, lengthOfInputString);
```